# How to decide the dynamic filed in solr using data type and without any suffix or prefix

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am indexing the RDBMS data into solr from my java application. For each row of a table I am creating a java bean and adding to solr server.(While creating a bean which is nothing but one solr document, I am using table's column name as field name of solr doc and corresponding value as solr field's value). But we support to index data from any number of tables , where each table will have different column names and data types. To, handle this we are using dynamic fields in schema.xml as below

<dynamicField name="*" **type="string"**  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

But the problem with this configuration is all the fields **type** is **String** , but I want to use numeric types for numeric data types in RDBMS and String for Varchar data type. Please suggest me how can I achieve this. I can't use suffix or prefix to field name while creating solr doc because I want to index and retrieve the docs using field name same as column name of table.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you can have a fields defined with *_Number and push your numberic fields to this field. Your java class should have the fields ending with that suffix...

Comment: Hi @AbhijitBashetti , Thank for your reply, but I can't use the suffix because same column names I need to show while retrieving documents .That's  why asking for an alternative .

Comment: The schemaless mode will kind of do what you want; it will guess based on the value submitted the first time for an unknown field. However, this will cause problems when a string field contains a numeric value the first time, and not at other times - the field will be created with a wrong data type. Then it becomes a question about whether you have data like that, and what kind of heuristic would actually work with the dataset you have to determine the type. There has to be some kind of deciding factor so that you are able to determine the type.

Comment: Having a utility script that describes / fetched the data types of each column in a table or set of tables and sets up a schema for that is probably the best way otherwise; if there is no way to determine the actual type of content from the value itself (and you can't do it by appending a type to the field name) the Solr side won't have anything useful to work with.